# Can't Join New Wifi?

Tags: networking, administrator

**My computer won't allow me to log into a new wifi network.**

I'm trying to join a wifi network but, upon every attempt to join, a message appears. The message reads:

> An application is attempting to perform an action that requires privileges. Authentication as the super user is required to perform this action.

It then asks for the "Password for root"

Does anyone know what this means and how to bypass it? It won't let me continue without the proper password.

Do I need to be an administrator to bypass this or no?

Comment: sounds like polkit. By default you can't add new networks without administrative password.

Comment: How do I fix this?

Comment: Use your password.

Comment: If you want to change polkits behavior you should rephrase your question.

Answer (score 2):

the "Password for root" is the password for whichever account you logged in and has the admin/root permissions

Let's say I have my user named Wattana Gaming and I want to install software or use sudo command it would asksomething like "Password for Wattana" right? That's the root(my account) password.
But be warned, if your account isn't an administrator account then you're done. go ask whoever own the PC to get the root password

If you want me to explain it shortly. it asking for your password

Comment: My brother created the profile, my younger brother... In the event that they can't remember the password - do you have any recommendations? Like would a factory reset work?

Comment: 1. reboot and hold shift while booting to enter GRUB menu
2. press e
3. find something like "ro quiet splash" and change it to "rw init=/bin/bash"
4. press E to go back
5. press b to boot
And that should send you right into the passwordless root shell.
After that I dont really know how to know the account password but you can do whatever you want at that root shell.
you can connect to network using nmcli(command only) or nmtui(text-based user interface)

Comment: Okaaaaaay... I'm gonna come right out and be honest, I rarely use code _manually_ and I have utterly no confidence in my ability to root around in the root shell if it means lasting damage to the only computer in the house :(

Comment: I have tried that and it totally safe. unless you mess something up. to connect to the internet, just type in nmtui. to install software, use sudo apt <install|remove|search> <software name>

Comment: Okay, I'll try it and see if it works...